# Comparing Merge Fields

Tags: microsoft-word, mail-merge

I am trying to do this:
{IF mergefield1 **Is greater than 5 and less than 2** "1" "2"}

Comparing the fields to get the answer is just not working for me.
Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that's what you're trying to compare - a number (your mergefield) can't be both greater than 2 AND less than 5 at the same time?

Comment: Thank you, I have worked it out.Formula for this range 1.85 to 2.02 IF within range add 0.17 to Value 1:

Value 1: «form_value_1»

IF value 1 is between (1.85 and 2.02) then add 0.17: 
FALSE